# How to track a segfault in PHP

Tags: php, segmentation-fault

I am developing a small-ish app in PHP. At some point a few days ago, PHP started to segfault on my dev machine (not a prod server) when I try to load and process some data in the app.

I attached gdb to try to see where the segfault happens, but basically got nowhere. The backtrace contains a bunch of `call_func` -esque things (about 50) and the last function was an `mpm_prefork` thing. I thought it was `mpm_prefork`'s fault so I installed php-fpm and tried using `mpm_event` instead, but it still segfaults.

I noticed that if I remove all data from database (I'm using SQLite), it would no longer segfault, so I tried exporting the data into a MySQL db, but it *still segfaults*.

In conclusion, it would seem the segfault occurs when the data from the db are loaded and processed for output.

I am using PHP 5.5.12 and Apache 2.4.9, both of which are (I believe) newest versions.

My question is: Can I somehow get the PHP's stack printed when the segfault occurs? Or perhaps could I have PHP log each function call somewhere to see what function call leads to the crash?

Also, does PHP have a stack limit? Am I possibly calling to many functions? (As far as I remember, there's no recursion involved in the process.)

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your PHP code until it gets to a seg-fault? That said, try disabling all unused extensions and ensuring your PHP binaries are all up-to-date.

Comment: Stepping through my code how? I don't have experience with xdebug if that's what you mean... EDIT: I can learn if need be though ;-)

Comment: It is not (AFAIK) possible to dump the PHP stack trace on a segfault - at that point, PHP is dead and won't be able to recover. Does PHP have a stack limit? Yes, absolutely, but hitting the limit doesn't usually result in a segfault. If you can't use xdebug, you might have to resort to debugging the "old fashioned" way, sprinkling `echo` and `print_r` statements through your code and seeing where it fails.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll look into xdebug see if I can use it...

Comment: Note that if you get a segfault, it's a bug in PHP or one of the extensions, probably NOT a bug in your script. Although your script may be doing something to trigger the bug. You should probably check the PHP bug tracker to see if the segfault is a known error.

Comment: Yeah, that occurred to me too, the problem is there's a whole bunch of segfault bugs in the bug tracker and I don't yet have any specific info on my segafult...

Comment: Ok, I installed xdebug and obtained a trace.

I'm pretty sure it's a stack overflow case, I've read somewhere that it causes a segfault on unix. The trace just goes on and on no matter what nesting limit I set in xdebug. It goes well over 5000 function calls. However the problem is in 3rd party library - RedBeanPHP.